# Making an Azure Terraform pipeline work with multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-rm

I am trying to get my main Terraform pipeline to deploy to multiple subscriptions, using the same service principle. Yet I keep getting errors that state resource group not found when it tries to deploy to the subscription. Both subscriptions are in the same tenant.

Here is my YAML Code:

```html
parameters:

- name: terraformWorkingDirectory
  type: string
  default: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/'

- name: serviceConnection
  type: string
  default: 'JasonTestEnvManagmentGroup'

- name: azureSubscription
  type: string
  default: 'JasonTestEnvManagmentGroup' 

- name: appconnectionname
  type: string
  default: 'JasonTestEnvManagmentGroup'
- name: RG
  type: string
  default: 'Jason_Testing_Terraform'

- name: azureLocation
  type: string
  default: 'UK South'

- name: terraformVersion
  type: string
  default: '1.0.4'

- name: artifactName
  type: string
  default: 'Website'

#- name: authartifactName
 # type: string
  #default: 'AuthServer'


# Only run against develop
#trigger:
 # branches:
  #  include:
    #  - main

#pool:
  #vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

# Don't run against PRs
#pr: none

#stages:

#- stage: terraformStage
#  displayName: Detect Drift

 # jobs:
  #- job: terraform_plan_and_apply

steps:
 - checkout: self

 - task: TerraformInstaller@0
   displayName: "install"
   inputs:
     terraformVersion: ${{ parameters.terraformVersion }}

 - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
   displayName: "init"
   inputs:
     provider: "azurerm"
     command: "init"
     backendServiceArm: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
     backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: "TerraformBackendForCICTesting"
     backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: "nsterraformstatestorage"
     backendAzureRmContainerName: "devopsterraformstatefile"
     backendAzureRmKey: "terraform.tfstate"
     workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}

 - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
   displayName: "plan"
   inputs:
     provider: "azurerm"
     command: "plan"
     commandOptions: "-input=false"
     environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
     workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}

 - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
   displayName: "apply"
   inputs:
     provider: "azurerm"
     command: "apply"
     commandOptions: "-input=false -auto-approve"
     environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
     workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}

  
#- stage: put_pipelines_files_in_place
#  displayName: Putting Pipeline Files In Place 

#- jobs:
  
  #- job: apply_artifiact_to_web_app
  #  displayName: Putting Files In Place 
  #  dependsOn: terraform_plan_and_apply


    # Download Artifact File
  #- download: none
 - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 # Website Artifact
   displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
   inputs:
     artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}
     patterns: '/website/**/*.zip'
     path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/website/'

    # deploy to Azure Web App 
 - task: AzureWebApp@1
   displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: nsclassroom-dgyn27h2dfoyojc' #Website Deploy Artifact
   inputs:
     package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/website/**/*.zip 
     azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
     ConnectedServiceName: ${{ parameters.appconnectionname}}
     appName: 'nsclassroom-dgyn27h2dfoyojc'
     ResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.RG}}

 - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 # Authentication Server Artifact
   displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
   inputs:
     artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName}}
     patterns: '/authsrv/**/*.zip'
     path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/authsrv/'

    # deploy to Azure Web App 
 - task: AzureWebApp@1
   displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: nsclassroomauthentication-dgyn27h2dfoyojc' #Authentication Server Deploy Artifact
   inputs:
     package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/authsrv/**/*.zip 
     azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
     ConnectedServiceName: ${{ parameters.appconnectionname}}
     appName: 'nsclassroomauthentication-dgyn27h2dfoyojc'
     ResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.RG}}
```

The agent is uses is the default Ubuntu agent.

The service connection I have tried two, one mapped to both of the subscriptions doesn't work. Another mapped and scoped to the Management group.

The original service principle did work until I brought in the second subscription.

Comment: Where do you specify your subscription id?

Comment: in these three places at the top of the yaml file: - name: serviceConnection
  type: string
  default: 'JasonTestEnvManagmentGroup'

- name: azureSubscription
  type: string
  default: 'JasonTestEnvManagmentGroup' 

- name: appconnectionname
  type: string
  default: 'JasonTestEnvManagmentGroup'

Comment: These are just parameters. Where do you use those values to instruct terraform to use the correct subscription?

Comment: here: backendServiceArm: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}

Comment: Yes, this is specifying the service connection but not the subscription id. Plus the backendServiceArm specifies the details regarding where the Azure Storage Account for the backend lives. This has nothing to do with the subscription id which is required when you need to run a plan. You need to find a way of providing it to the plan task. A viable way would be through env variables.

Comment: Ahh okay do you have a working example of this please?

Comment: Hi @Jason how did you end up solving this?

Comment: I was given a sort of solution by MS but I haven't tested it yet. I moved onto another project and will probably come back to this at the end of the year. The solution was to make a changing parameter, with logic with YAML seemed very far fetched though.